# How to make a more accurate voltage divider?

Tags: voltage, resistors

I tried to make a circuit as a voltage divider, for which I used three 5kohms resistors and a 9V battery (actually is 9.5V.) I tested the V<sub>out</sub> between 3 resistors that are:

- 3.183
- 3.179
- 3.146

When I tried to use one V<sub>out</sub> to light an LED (green), and expected the voltage to be 3.1V, I found it is actually 2.59V

The tested V<sub>out</sub> of 3 resistors is:

- 3.481
- 3.441
- 2.59

Why doesn't the divider divide equally? How do they make the V<sub>out</sub> of a 555 timer equally divided?
[image]

Comment: The LED is, effectively, a resistor in parallel with that bottom-most 5k resistor. So the resistance of that lower part is less than 5k when you connect the LED.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the resistors divide the voltage evenly only if they are equal and when there is no load.

Your resistors clearly have some manufacturing tolerance in their resistances.

When you put a LED over one of the resistors, the LED will be biased to some voltage and current it happens to have at that operating point. So the voltage divider has output impedance that is about 3.33k and any load will bring down the voltage.

The difference to resistors inside NE555 is that there is no (or only very little) load on them, and they have more likely tighter manufacturing tolerance, but according to the datasheet there can be over 20% tolerance when measuring the CONT pin voltage that comes from the divider.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to learn about voltages dividers is that you need to consider the effect of the load. In this case, the LED voltage vs. current curve controls the voltage to a great extent. The forward voltage drop of the LED does not change very much over quite a wide range of current. The LED is essentially acting as a shunt voltage regulator.